# How do I reference buildsrc from src

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

This might be an XY problem but, I am working on a JavaCard project (Java Embedded) and I have a Kotlin Gradle build for the installation. I have some Kotlin code in my buildSrc folder, which is used to calculate some of the installation parameters. I know I can't use Kotlin code on my JavaCard itself.

I do have to pass some custom TLVs to the JavaCard in the installation parameters though, and I want a single source of truth for the Tag values.

My idea was to create a Java interface containing all custom tag values as constants. I want to use these constants in my gradle build, so I think I should put them in buildSrc. I also want to use this interface in my Configuration class that parses the incoming parameters. How do I reference buildSrc from src?

I tried creating a interface at `buildSrc/src/main/java/<same_package_as_src>/InstallTags`, but the code doesn't see it. NB: `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin` should not be included in the main project

Comment: You can't. The proper solution would be to define those in a separate module or library, and add that as a dependency to both your normal project and the buildSrc.

Comment: If these constants are determined at build time, and you essentially want to "inject" the values during the build, then you could probably have Gradle generate a source file (before compilation) or populate a resource file that you load at run-time.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried that but even though I add my ":common" module as a dependency to buildSrc, it doesn't see it. Also, I can only install a single jar on the JavaCard, and it seems that the multiple modules will split into multiple jars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "right" way to share code between the build and the main project would be to make use of an [included build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). Then you can import both a plugin and a module from that included build.

You can do what you've suggested though, even though it's an anti-pattern. You can add the compiled `buildSrc` Kotlin code<sup>1</sup> as dependency of your main code by writing:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(
        files(rootProject.projectDir.resolve("buildSrc/build/classes/kotlin/main"))
    )
}
```

This a bit of a 'hack' and it won't add in any dependencies the `buildSrc` code might need. However, in a simple case, this may be acceptable.

---

<sup>1</sup> For any Java code, simply replace `kotlin` with `java` in the path